# Problems with UIRefreshControl and UITableView bounce back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Employed on multiple `UITableView`s in my project, I have problems with bounce back in the `UITableView` for the last `UITableViewCell`. When I scroll down to the end of the list I can never view the last cell. I'll have to continue to hold on the scroll in order to see it. I originally employed a `UIRefreshControl` on the `UITableViewCell`, but I've since removed it and it doesn't fix the problem. These problems started once I employed a `UIRefreshControl`. I have no new data to add on at the end of the `UITableView`, so implementing another cell wouldn't help.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the autoresizing for it in the nib. It will be because of the table goes out of screen.

Comment: All I did was add auto layout and it fixed the problem. Thanks!